# Whitelisting images from Docker Hub for binary authorization in GCP

Tags: docker, security, google-cloud-platform

We are attempting to setup binary authorization in our project and we are having issues whitelisting images from docker hub. An example of this problem is trying to whitelist the images needed for Ambassador. We were able to whitelist `quay.io/datawire/ambassador:0.39.0` because it gave us the image repository in the error message

> Image quay.io/datawire/ambassador:0.39.0 denied

We are not able to whitelist `datawire/prom-statsd-exporter:0.6.0` since it did not give us the image repository

> Image datawire/prom-statsd-exporter:0.6.0 denied

We have tried prefixing the image with every registry we could think of (hub.docker.io, docker.io, registry.docker.io, mirror.gcr.io, registry.hub.docker.com, etc...). Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm having the same issue and I'm wondering if you found the correct url ?

Comment: I did not, holding off on Binary Auth for now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Solution for me was to edit the manifests and prefix the images with the registry e.g. `docker.io`.

As far as I can tell the API expects the full path in the form: `registry/path/to/image`

https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.policy#AdmissionWhitelistPattern